# The link to stackexchange.com in the Stack Exchange dropdown is not recognizable as a link

Tags: feature-request, status-bydesign, design, stack-exchange-button

The Stack Exchange dropdown was very recently changed to the format in this screenshot:

[image: Stack Exchange dropdown]

The item highlighted by the red circle is a link to the list of all SE sites on stackexchange.com. The two items highlighted in blue are not links.

When this change went live I almost posted a feature request to bring back the link to stackexchange.com, as I use that one quite often. I simply missed at first that the link was still there as it just does not look like a link.

Please mark this link in some way so that it does not look like the other unlinked headers.

Comment: I think at least the "your communities" header [should be a link too](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/218142/your-communities-in-site-switcher-menu-should-be-a-link). I suppose the "current community" header could be linked too (e.g. to the font page of the current site), just for the sake of consistency, even if it's kind of redundant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We don't actually want to draw much attention to these links. They're intended to be just for power users who happen to find them.

So with that in mind, we'd rather not add any symbols to those headers at the moment. We are, however, fixing them so that [all of the headers link somewhere](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/219672/155160).

Comment: Anna, while you're at it something truly minor. Under "more stack exchange communities" the textbox placeholder is "Find a Stack Exchange **site**" emphasis mine... shouldn't it be "Find a Stack Exchange community"?

Comment: @ShadowWizard Well spotted. Will fix.

Answer (score 5):

I agree.

I think a common indicator of this kind is an arrow, for example Wikipedia's icon for external links:

[image]

Another example (of appearance, not functionality), in iTunes:

[image]

I think something as simple as,

[image]

miniaturized, would do the trick. Because changing the color of the text (to say, blue, as is standard) would make the interface look messy, IMHO.

---

### Sidenote

Can we also add `cursor: default` on the other labels, "Current Community" and "Your Communities?" The text obviously isn't editable, and no one should need to select that text. 95% of the time we toggle that dropdown, we're gonna have to cross those labels to click on any of the links; I feel that preserving the default cursor would look more pleasing, again, IMHO.