# "Your communities" in site switcher menu should be a link

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, top-bar, stack-exchange-button, navigation

This is not a link:

[image: Screenshot of site switcher menu, with "your communities" circled]

I think it *should* be a link.

(Specifically, I think it should link to the same place as the "*#* Accounts" header in the user profile summary does, i.e. `http://stackexchange.com/users/<id>/<name>?tab=accounts`.)

Comment: Somewhat Related: [The link to stackexchange.com in the Stack Exchange dropdown is not recognizable as a link](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/217912/the-link-to-stackexchange-com-in-the-stack-exchange-dropdown-is-not-recognizable)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Great idea! This will go live in the next build.

We will also be linking "Current Community" to the home page of the site you're on mostly for consistency between all headers.